# New to Python 3.4+ Scripting and writing JSON text files and saving them

Tags: python, json

I'm currently trying to write a script in Python that can manipulate JSON ".txt" files within a folder and saving it as a new JSON ".txt" file within the same folder.  I already know how to manipulate the file, but I'd need to manually type in the actual path.  Is there a way to just type in the folder name and the name of the text file to just manipulate that instead of typing the full path?

Because right now, I'm having it to do

```
    import json
    simple_path = input('Please input the path directory: ")
    >>> 'c:\user\path1\path2\simple.txt'
    with open (simple_path,'r+') as f:
        simple_data = json.load(f)
        somefunction()
        f.seek(0)
        out_file = open('c://user//path1//path2//simple_edit.txt','w')
        json.dump(simple_data, out_file)
```

each time I want to manipulate a specific JSON text files, I'd have to change the whole path, and I'd have to edit "out_file" manually every single time, so I can I make it more flexible?

since I'll be placing the script into a main folder with all the sub-folders and JSON Files.  It'd be easier for me to manipulate the sub-folder JSON text files without having to put the full path.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying, but take a look at this module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily do that with the os module

```
import os

folder = input('please enter the folder:')

file = input('enter the filename:')

print('C'+os.path.join(os.sep, folder, file))
```

`os.path.join` constructs the path to the file by joining the strings you supplied to it and adding the correct file separator (`/` in *nix systems and `\` on windows)

while `os.sep` returns a string of the root directory which will be `/` in *nix systems and `\` in windows

Answer (score 0):

For the input, relative paths may be sufficient. For the output, just generate the filename from the input filename by adding '_edit' using `os.path.splitext()`.

```
import json
import os

def edit_json(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        simple_data = json.load(f)
        somefunction()
        f.seek(0)
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        out_file = open(base + '_edit' + ext, 'w')
        json.dump(simple_data, out_file)

simple_path = input('Please input the path directory: ")
>>> 'path2\simple.txt'

edit_json(simple_path)
```

Comment: You have to pass `simple data as an argument: `somefunction(simple_data)` and `def somefunction(data): ...`